# add desktop environment to a VirtualBox VM

Tags: virtualbox, desktop-environments

I am working with a VirtualBox headless virtual machine (Mininet VM running Ubuntu 20.04) and I want to install a desktop environment, is that possible? if so, how?

Comment: `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` will install the default Ubuntu Desktop (eg. GNOME).  You can also install other DEs; eg. `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop` will install the Lubuntu (LXQt) desktop...  (etc.. applies for all [flavors](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) too; I just used Lubuntu as example)

Comment: @guiverc yes, this answers my question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is straight forward as @guiverc commented:

> `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` will install the default Ubuntu Desktop (eg. GNOME). You can also install other DEs; eg. `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop` will install the Lubuntu (LXQt) desktop... (etc.. applies for all flavors too; I just used Lubuntu as example) –
> guiverc

note: the terminal does not work by default even though there is an app called "terminal" installed, so I used Xterm instead (you can install GNOME terminal using Xterm).